# Facebook app test users can't see app

Tags: facebook, testing

I've started to create an app and I've created a few test users but when I login as them and try and find the app, it doesn't show up.

Comment: I think the users needs to be admins or developers in order to see the app.

Comment: Do you mean an actual test account or a facebook user who has the tester role?

Answer (score -1):

You have to submit App to Public Directory Listing then only users can see app.
Basic criteria for submitting app is to have 5 monthy active users (may be more as per new FB changes).

For now you can use app page URL directly if you want Users to visit app.

Comment: Ok thanks, works fine when using the url directly. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: This isn't how search works anymore, there's no manual submission process. Search submission is automatic and takes place every 2-4 weeks now